# why pycharm use different python when os.system('python main.py')

Tags: python, linux, path, operating-system, os.system

My environment is ubuntu 14, Python 2.7 .  When I run a program directly and with function os.system(), it uses different python interpreter. My code is as below:

---

```
# script.py
import tensorflow as tf
import os

print tf.__version__
print tf.__path__

command = 'python main.py'
os.system(command)
```

---

```
# main.py
import tensorflow as tf

print tf.__version__
print tf.__path__
```

---

when I run scripy.py, I got

```
1.2.1
['/home/Monday/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow']
0.12.1
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow']
```

when I run main.py, I got

```
1.2.1
['/home/Monday/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow']
```

I have set my Interpreter as below:

```
Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7
```

Comment: How did you configure it?

Comment: sorry, what does the 'configure' mean?

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm is running the Python in `/home/Monday/Applications/anaconda2` but when you do `os.system()` it runs whatever Python is in your `PATH` environment variable.  To fix this, you can change your PyCharm run settings to set the PATH environment variable to put the Anaconda Python first.

But better still, you should simply not invoke Python from Python.  Change `main.py` to be an importable module instead of a "main" script that you execute.  Then it will be simple: just `import main` (or whatever it's called), and invoke functions on it.  This is a more proper design, and is more efficient too.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me how to change `Path Environment variable`?